# How to check if user has rated a chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I have a chrome extension and I want to remind users to leave a rating, but I don't want to annoy them by always showing the rating call to action. Is there a way to check if the user has rated the extension? If there is no way, any ideas how to limit the call to action so it's less annoying?

Maybe only show the message every 10 days or something similar?

Comment: You can't check. There is no API and chrome extensions can't run on the chrome marketplace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An amazing way is to have a button that will permanently disable the reminder. The last thing you want is to have someone who becomes angry at the persistent pop-ups is to leave a negative review. A single pop-up after several days of using lets a user decide if they like a product, and if they are largely satisfied they will be willing to leave a review.

I have definitely left a negative review over too many pop-ups, and it takes just one too many to push a user to that point.

Comment: Seconded. I would add that you should ask yourself why you made the extension in the first place. Was it because you wanted to add value to the experience of users or for "fame and fortune"? It's always nice to get recognition for what you did, but do you want to nag people in order to get it?